# how to change/remove new relic license key once it has been added

Tags: newrelic

I have already added a license key to one of my servers but now I realize that I should add different key instead. so I just want to remove it and add another one

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

What server are you running, or what kind of installation procedure have you followed?

In case you have installed it on Tomcat it suffices to change your license key in the newrelic.yml config file